# Hibernate criteria distinct vs group property

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have searched everywhere and cannot find any reason for this behaviour.

I am using Hibernate which connects to an oracle database. When doing a query using Criteria, there are a few joins (one left outer join) and some restrictions. I set a projection of

```
Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id"))
```

and run the query (criteria.list()). This then takes approximately 1h 45m to return.

I then attempt to run the query directly against the database using sql developer and that takes 0.045s.

So I debugged through the criteria and found that the projection was causing the time delay (running the query without the projections returned in 0.5s). Changed the projection to be

```
Projections.groupProperty("id")
```

returns in 0.25s.

Is there a difference between these 2 projections? I see both queries running against the database but one is taking much longer than the other.

Note:
I am using Hibernate version 4.3.7.Final

Comment: Turn on hibernate SQL logs and see what SQL it generates. That should help

Comment: That is how i got the sql to run directly against the database. I turned the hibernate logging to trace level and turned sql on. This then gave me the exact query to run

Comment: I also ran that direct query using session.executeSql(query) instead of the criteria version and that returned quickly too

Comment: Well then you should try to debug & profile, see what's exactly taking the time, there might be an issue with your java code. Or a bug in Hibernate, which is unlikely :)